# Can citeindex and bibindex contain section number in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, appendix

I hope the serial numbers of references in the appendix include section number. That is, `[1]`->`[A.1]`, `[2]`->`[A.2]`, `[3]`->`[B.1]`, `[4]`->`[B.2]`, `[5]`->`[B.3]`. Just like the equation number shown by following command.

```latex
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter-\arabic{equation}}
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A,title={A}}
@article{B,title={B}}
@article{C,title={C}}
@article{D,title={D}}
@article{E,title={E}}
@article{F,title={G}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=gb7714-2015]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\section{mainbody}
text\cite{A}
text\cite{B}
\printbibliography

\appendix

\begin{refsection}

\section{appendix 1}
text\cite{C}
text\cite{A}
\section{appendix 2}
text\cite{D,E,F}
\printbibliography

\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]